# Index on DATE(column)

Tags: mysql, sql

if i use the following to compare a `date` with a `datetime`

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE DATE(startTime) = '2010-04-29'
```

can i still use a index on `startTime` ?

after i create a index :

```
create index mi_date on calendar(startTime);
```

explain result :

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar     | index | NULL          | mi_date | 6       | NULL |   25 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

and with query

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE startTime like '2010-04-29 %'
```

explain cmd :

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar     | index | mi_date       | mi_date | 6       | NULL |   25 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

the diference between the first explain is that column `possible_keys` is not null.

And there is also this query :

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE startTime BETWEEN '2010-04-29 00:00:00' AND '2010-04-29 23:59:59'
```

explain :

```
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table        | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | calendar     | range | mi_date       | mi_date | 6       | NULL |   16 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+--------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+------+--------------------------+
```

the column type is range and the rows scanned are less just 16 which is the result of my query.

p.s : i have 25 rows in my table.

Comment: The column key show, mysql use a index "mi_date" and he checks 16 rows from 25.

Comment: Index in explain column type will tell you: "The index join type is the same as ALL, except that the index tree is scanned." So all 25 row are checked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With EXPLAIN

```
mysql> EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE DATE(startTime) = '2010-04-29'
```

you can check index using from mysql. But normaly MySQl dont' use a index using DATE().

Try

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE startTime BETWEEN '2010-04-29 00:00:00' AND '2010-04-29 23:59:59'
```

Comment: i update my question with explain cmd can you tell if mysql use my index ?

Comment: It seems so, that MySQL use your new index. => Column: type show index. How many rows did this table hold  ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM calendar )?

Comment: 25 rows. so it seems that even column type show index he use a full scan. not ?

Comment: No, MySQL don't really use the index, MySQL just scan the index to find row matched your query. This called index scan and is faster than table scan ( http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html#explain-join-types )

Comment: but what is the diference between index scan and using a index not the same ? and i notice the column `possible_keys` is null.

Comment: index-scan: MySQL just scan the small index file, but he scan the complete file

Comment: use the index: MySQL use the index is much fast than index-scan. Try my QUERY with between and pelase show this explan.

Comment: i add it to my question .. now i need which is the best because i try also @vivoconunxino answer.

Comment: Range is no problem. But EXPLAIN will show you the best way. The less row the better (faster). Current table contains 25 rows and your query scan 25 rows. Maybe there is only one or two matches. Explain Column row maybe show 10 rows it's faster. But column rows don't show the exact result, it's just a guess from mysql

Answer (score 1):

You can know it adding "Explain" before your query, this will report with keys are being used. Usually the use of functions disables indexed searchs, but you could perfectly use indexes modifying your query:

```
SELECT * FROM `calendar` WHERE startTime like '2010-04-29 %'
```

Well, as you can see in the results of the Explain, in this case (yours, using date(..) ) mysql is already using the index. Check the ref field:

> ref – Shows the columns or constants that are compared to the index
>   named in the key column. MySQL will either pick a constant value to be
>   compared or a column itself based on the query execution plan. You can
>   see this in the example given below.

Which is better? At this point they must be likely the same. You can try other queries and take a look at the rows field.

> rows – lists the number of records that were examined to produce the
>   output. This Is another important column worth focusing on optimizing
>   queries, especially for queries that use JOIN and subqueries.

The on with less rows examined is the best.

Comment: it's because when using jokers (%) you have to use the 'like' operator instead of '='. Edited

Comment: now it works and i update my question with explain cmd if you can tell me if it's the better way.

Comment: You've been answered,  they're likely the same.